# Powershell process single array in foreach loop versus multi aray in foreach loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

i have 3 arrays with 3 elements in each array

when i run it in foreach loop it works just fine and produces desired results

```
$OHSS_AU_Params = 'OU=ActiveUsers,OU=OHSS_Users,OU=OHSS,OU=HCCSS,DC=test,DC=ssh', '66-66-66-66', '66-OHSS'
   $01_ESC_AU_Params = 'OU=ActiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=01 Erie St. Clair,OU=CCAC,DC=test,DC=ssh', '01-01-01-01', '01-ESC'
   $02_SW_AU_Params = 'OU=ActiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=02 South West,OU=CCAC,DC=test,DC=ssh', '02-02-02-02', '02-SW'

   $All_OUs = $OHSS_AU_Params, $01_ESC_AU_Params, $02_SW_AU_Params

    foreach ($OU in $All_OUs)
    {
        write-host "`n Search -> " $OU[0]
        write-host " EmployeeID -> " $OU[1]
        write-host " LegacyName -> " $OU[2]
    
    }
```

output

```
Search ->  OU=ActiveUsers,OU=OHSS_Users,OU=OHSS,OU=HCCSS,DC=test,DC=ssh
EmployeeID ->  66-66-66-66
LegacyName ->  66-OHSS

Search ->  OU=ActiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=01 Erie St. Clair,OU=CCAC,DC=test,DC=ssh
EmployeeID ->  01-01-01-01
LegacyName ->  01-ESC

Search ->  OU=ActiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=02 South West,OU=CCAC,DC=test,DC=ssh
EmployeeID ->  02-02-02-02
LegacyName ->  02-SW
```

but when the number of arrays changes to only one

```
$All_OUs = $OHSS_AU_Params
```

i get this

```
Search ->  O
EmployeeID ->  U
LegacyName ->  =

Search ->  6
EmployeeID ->  6
LegacyName ->  -

Search ->  6
EmployeeID ->  6
LegacyName ->  -
```

how can i check if the array is a single array with 3 elements

i tried modifying the foreach loop as in

```
foreach ($OU in $All_OUs)
{
   write-host "`n Search -> " @($OU)[0]
   write-host " EmployeeID -> " @($OU)[1]
   write-host " LegacyName -> " @($OU)[2]
}
```

but still i get 3 iterations in the loop instead of just one, but looks better now

```
Search ->  OU=ActiveUsers,OU=OHSS_Users,OU=OHSS,OU=HCCSS,DC=test,DC=ssh
EmployeeID ->
LegacyName ->

Search ->  66-66-66-66
EmployeeID ->
LegacyName ->

Search ->  66-OHSS
EmployeeID ->
LegacyName ->
```

but what i need is just a single iteration to look like this

```
Search ->  OU=ActiveUsers,OU=OHSS_Users,OU=OHSS,OU=HCCSS,DC=test,DC=ssh
EmployeeID -> 66-66-66-66
LegacyName -> 66-OHSS
```

sorry my English is not the best.

thank you

Comment: In all honesty, this approach is flawed to begin with, would you like to see an alternative that would be more robust ?

Comment: It works when i have multiple arrays, and for most of the time it will be multiple arrays, but please could you show me a different way of doing it as i will have about 14 arrays with 3 elements in them, i guess there is always better more efficient ways of coding the same thing. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why PowerShell does this is because on your second example, `$All_OUs` is an *array* while on your first example, `$All_OUs` is an *array of arrays*.

You could force `$All_OUs` to be an *array of arrays* by adding the [Comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-):

```
$OHSS_AU_Params = 'OU=ActiveUsers,OU=OHSS_Users,OU=OHSS,OU=HCCSS,DC=test,DC=ssh', '66-66-66-66', '66-OHSS'
$All_OUs = , $OHSS_AU_Params

foreach ($OU in $All_OUs) {
    Write-Host "`n Search -> " $OU[0]
    Write-Host " EmployeeID -> " $OU[1]
    Write-Host " LegacyName -> " $OU[2]
}
```

However, a more robust approach would be to use a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2), by doing so you would not have a need to validate if the *collection* is an *array* or an *array of arrays*:

```
$toProcess = @{
    'OU=ActiveUsers,OU=OHSS_Users,OU=OHSS,OU=HCCSS,DC=test,DC=ssh' = '66-66-66-66', '66-OHSS'
    'OU=ActiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=01 Erie St. Clair,OU=CCAC,DC=test,DC=ssh' = '01-01-01-01', '01-ESC'
    'OU=ActiveUsers,OU=Users,OU=02 South West,OU=CCAC,DC=test,DC=ssh' = '02-02-02-02', '02-SW'
}

foreach ($key in $toProcess.PSBase.Keys) {
    # => `$values` is the array with EmployeeID and LegacyName for each `$key` (OU)
    $values = $toProcess[$key]
    Write-Host "`n Search -> " $key
    Write-Host " EmployeeID -> " $values[0]
    Write-Host " LegacyName -> " $values[1]
}
```

Comment: both examples will work in my situation, i did not know about hash table option as I'm still learning more about powershell in general.

Comment: @RobertK happy you could learn something new :)